# Version of \smash that still stretches, shrinks and allows linebreaks

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, height

Is it possible to set the height, depth or total height — optionally — of some content in a paragraph to zero while still allowing its white spaces to stretch or shrink and linebreaks to occur? Maybe with LuaTeX and Lua code?

Comment: You might also look at \raisebox, but like \smash it applies to boxes, not individual letters.

Answer (score 1):

Without an MWE from the OP, I can only speculate on what type of content he wishes to process.  Here, I use the `tokcycle` package to create a pseudo-environment `\smashstream`.  As you see white space can stretch/shrink to satisfy margin constraints.

EDITED to handle *simple* math.  For such cases, tokens that you don't want smashed must be intercepted in the character directive, such as `$`, `^`, and `_`.  Things like `\frac` will not be smashed, because it is a macro, not a character.

Downside: hyphenation, kerning, and ligatures will not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\tokcycleenvironment\smashstream
  {\tctestifx{_##1}{\addcytoks{##1}}
   {\tctestifx{^##1}{\addcytoks{##1}}
    {\tctestifx{$##1}{\addcytoks{##1}}
     {\addcytoks{\smash{##1}}}}}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\smashstream\Huge This is a test of the emergency broadcast 
  system...this is only a \huge $y = x^{2} + y_{i}$
  test\normalsize\endsmashstream
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The content to be processed is text and mathematical formulas.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. Although not very complex, the formulas won’t be that simple and I’d rather not smash every single character/token, which has the downside of altering spacing between symbols.